What's the easiest way to pack all the header files in Bazel with pkg_tar to release library?
I am new to Bazel, but I want to release a library to other with headers and shared library.
My code tree looks likes this (but with more subdirectories):
root

feature1

feature1.hpp
feature1.cpp
BUILD


feature2

feature2.hpp
feature2.cpp
BUILD


feature3

feature3.hpp
feature3.cpp
BUILD


BUILD

I want to package a tar.gz file in the root BUILD with lib and include,

cc_binary(
    name = "feature_impl",
    deps = [
       ":feature1",
       ":feature2",
       ":feature3",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "feature",
    linkshared = True,
    deps = [":feature_impl"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "headers"
    srcs = XXXXXXX
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "headers_pkg"
    srcs = "headers",
    package_dir = "include",
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "feature_pkg"
    srcs = ":feature",
    package_dir = "lib"
)

How can I package all the headers with sub directores structures ??
Now I have to write a pkg_tar target in the BUILD of every subdirectory.`
Is there a rule like "sub_glob" for filegrouop?

You can’t glob into a subdirectory containing a BUILD or a BUILD.bazel file.

The answer depends a bit on what you have in your featureX/BUILD files, and if you have them in the first place.
In the case you don't have BUILD files in the subdirectories:
Should be enough to define:
load("@rules_pkg//pkg:tar.bzl", "pkg_tar")

filegroup(
    name = "headers",
    srcs = glob([
        "feature*/*.hpp",
    ]),
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "headers_pkg",
    srcs = [
        ":headers",
    ],
    strip_prefix = ".",
)

To get the following structure in tar:
$ tar -tf bazel-bin/headers_pkg.tar
feature1/
feature1/feature1.hpp
feature2/
feature2/feature2.hpp
feature3/
feature3/feature3.hpp

In case you need the BUILD files in the sub directories
You can define the filegroup for headers of each feature:
feature1/BUILD.bazel:
filegroup(
    name = "headers",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.hpp"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

and then create your package from all 3 filegroups:
load("@rules_pkg//pkg:tar.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "headers_pkg",
    srcs = [
        "//feature1:headers",
        "//feature2:headers",
        "//feature3:headers",
    ],
    strip_prefix = ".",
)

The resulting archive will look the same as in the first example.
